# Is a Separate Function Preferred for 2 Lines of Repeated Code in Swift?

Tags: swift, function, standards

I am designing a small game, and have decided on an initial way to distribute points based on the number of seconds elapsed between the time a question was asked and an enter button was pressed.

I understand that best practice is to create a function to call when lines are going to be repeated, but it seems to me that it may be a little excessive to call it when there are only two lines repeated four times.  Using the code below, would it be "proper" or preferred for me to create a function for the last two lines in each section?

```
//Assigns points to score based on elapsed time and updates score
func updateScore() {

    timer.invalidate()

    if timeToAnswer < 3 {
        questionScore = 10  //10 points for answering so quickly
        score = score + questionScore  //Updates score
        timeToAnswer = 0  //Resets var timeToAnswer
    }

    else if (timeToAnswer >= 3) && (timeToAnswer < 6) {
        questionScore = 7
        score = score + questionScore
        timeToAnswer = 0
    }

    else if (timeToAnswer >= 6) && (timeToAnswer < 11) {
        questionScore = 10 - timeToAnswer
        score = score + questionScore
        timeToAnswer = 0
    }

    else {
        questionScore = 1
        score = score + questionScore
        timeToAnswer = 0
    }
}
```

Thank you very much to anybody that offers assistance or advice.

Comment: The intuition is correct (DRY), but in this case, no separate function is needed. Just move those two lines after the final `else` clause, like Michele demonstrated, and then you can remove those lines from each of the closures.

Comment: I’d suggest `switch` statement, too: https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/00a03ab3cf7ba38f3768452942c3b693

Comment: I like that version also, thanks Rob!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a better way.
You can use switch statement, too. Anyway:

```
func updateScore() {

    timer.invalidate()

    if timeToAnswer < 3 {
        questionScore = 10
    }

    else if (timeToAnswer >= 3) && (timeToAnswer < 6) {
        questionScore = 7
    }

    else if (timeToAnswer >= 6) && (timeToAnswer < 11) {
        questionScore = 10 - timeToAnswer
    }

    else {
        questionScore = 1
    }

    score = score + questionScore  //Updates score
    timeToAnswer = 0  //Resets var timeToAnswer
}
```

Comment: I'll accept it since it works and cleans up the code.  Thanks Michele!